# PyQt QtSql возвращает false при like запросе

Tags: sql, python-2.x, pyqt4

При попытке запроса записей с использованием Like в MySQL QtSql возвращает false.При том же запросе в БД - работает.В чем может быть проблема?

```
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setDatabaseName("vista")
db.setUserName("root")
db.setPassword("Secret")

if not db.open():
    QMessageBox.critical(None, "Database Error", db.lastError().text())   

query = QSqlQuery()
query.exec_("SELECT * FROM vista.user WHERE fio LIKE '%Something%' ")

self.tableSearch = QTableWidget()
self.tableSearch.setColumnCount(query.record().count())
self.tableSearch.setRowCount(query.size())

i = 0
while query.next():
    self.tableSearch.setItem(i, 0, QTableWidgetItem(query.value(0).toString()))
    self.tableSearch.setItem(i, 1, QTableWidgetItem(query.value(1).toString()))
    self.tableSearch.setItem(i, 2, QTableWidgetItem(query.value(2).toString()))
    self.tableSearch.setItem(i, 3, QTableWidgetItem(query.value(3).toString()))
    self.tableSearch.setItem(i, 4, QTableWidgetItem(query.value(4).toString()))
    self.tableSearch.setItem(i, 5, QTableWidgetItem(query.value(5).toString()))  

    i += 1   

self.tableSearch.show()
```

Comment: а пробовали вы какой нибудь другой select сделать? Да даже просто `SELECT * FROM vista.user`?

Comment: В другом виджете работает, а в этом  нет.

Comment: Пробовали вызвать `lastError` чтобы посмотреть были ли ошибки при выполнении запроса?

Comment: Да,ошибок не было.